# PHP OpenSSL encrypt with DES-CBC algorithm unexpected output

Tags: php, des, php-openssl

I want to change all the passwords of a given DB. All this passwords are cipher with DES CBC PKCS7, I have the key and the initialization vector. I've used the next web page http://www.txtwizard.net/crypto to decrypt one password and the result was the expected (using options DES, CBC and PKCS7).

**key:** RRZy0njZDzw=

**iv:** p/34qWLNYfg=

**plain text**  123123

**crypted text** x541kJ4KvJo=

But when the next code written in PHP I can't replicate the result:

```
<?php
    $key = "RRZy0njZDzw=";
    $iv = "p/34qWLNYfg=";
    $data = "123123";
    $cipher='DES-CBC';
    var_dump(openssl_get_cipher_methods());
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data,$cipher, $key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);
    echo base64_encode($encrypted);
?>
```

The output of this code is:

```
PHP Warning:  openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 12 bytes long which is longer than the 8 expected by selected cipher, truncating in /home/sergio/Documents/DevEnvTest/siaf/aes2hash.php on line 7

Warning: openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 12 bytes long which is longer than the 8 expected by selected cipher, truncating in /home/sergio/Documents/DevEnvTest/siaf/aes2hash.php on line 7
gB7ahDoYZqI=
```

Is there a way to get the same string that the online tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decode your key and IV from Base64:

```
$key = base64_decode("RRZy0njZDzw=");
$iv = base64_decode("p/34qWLNYfg=");
```